# InstallScript CA changes done in registry are not removed on uninstall

Tags: installshield, basic-msi

I have A Basis MSI project created with InstallShield 2018.
The setup include some InstallScript CA that modify the registry ( I should have done it inside a component but due to some limitation it's done by code )
Now I have located the CA between the InstallInitialize and CostFinalize action with NOT REMOVE="ALL" condition.
The code works well on install by while uninstall these changes are not deleted.

Should it work this way ?

Answer (score 0):

That is just a condition that must be true at runtime. So it's basically saying do not run this custom action when uninstalling.

Since you're creating the registry values in your CA the MSI has no clue about them during uninstall. You'll probably need to write another CA to remove them on uninstall and condition it to run on uninstall (REMOVE=ALL)